# How can you remove equal objects from containers (but not necessarily the same object)?

Tags: python, object, set, containers

I want to do something like:

```
class Thing(object):
    self.mySet = Set()
    self.mySet.add(Cell((0,0),25))
    self.mySet.add(Cell((0,1),50))
    self.mySet.add(Cell((0,2),75))

    def ClaimCell(self, cell):
        self.mySet.remove(cell)

class Cell(object):
    def __init__(self,index,value):
        self.index = index
        self.value = value
```

But essentially, I want to be able to do a look-up based on the members of the `Cell`, rather than the instance itself. I would like to be able to just test if the `cell.index` passed in matches any `cell.index` within the `self.mySet`. Is there a `__cmp__` type method I can override for this? Or am I forced to loop through the Set, checking the index every time, and then manually removing that corresponding entry?

Comment: What's up with the capital-S Set?

Comment: Did you try overriding `__eq__`? (On the Cell class)

Comment: @user2357112 -- hm, it's just what I found over at https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

Comment: @MrDuk: As it says at the top of that page, that module is deprecated.  `set` (with a lowercase s) is now a builtin type.

Comment: Perhaps you can just use a dictionary ``{cell.index: cell}`` instead of a set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, two objects which are similar are not the same. Quoting the documentation of [`__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__),

> If a class does not define a `__cmp__()` or `__eq__()` method it should not define a `__hash__()` operation either; if it defines `__cmp__()` or `__eq__()` but not `__hash__()`, its instances will not be usable in hashed collections. If a class defines mutable objects and implements a `__cmp__()` or `__eq__()` method, it should not implement `__hash__()`, since hashable collection implementations require that a object’s hash value is immutable (if the object’s hash value changes, it will be in the wrong hash bucket).
>
> User-defined classes have `__cmp__()` and `__hash__()` methods by default; with them, **all objects compare unequal** (except with themselves) and `x.__hash__()` returns a result derived from `id(x)`.

So, if you want to treat two objects identical, you need to override both `__eq__` and `__hash__` methods, like this

```
class Cell(object):

    def __init__(self, index, value):
        self.index = index
        self.value = value

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.index)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return other.index == self.index

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Index: {}, Value: {}".format(self.index, self.value)
```

Since you want to compare based on the `index`, only `index` is hashed and returned in the overridden `__hash__` method.

If two hash values are equal, then Python will check if both the objects are the same by internally calling `__eq__` method. So, we override that method also and return just the result of comparing `index` of two objects,

```
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return other.index == self.index
```

We have overridden the `__repr__` just to see the actual elements when printed.

Now, when you do something like this

```
class Thing(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.mySet = set()
        self.mySet.add(Cell((0, 0), 25))
        self.mySet.add(Cell((0, 1), 50))
        self.mySet.add(Cell((0, 2), 75))

    def ClaimCell(self, cell):
        self.mySet.remove(cell)
        print(self.mySet)

Thing().ClaimCell(Cell((0, 1), 99))
```

You will get

```
set([Index: (0, 0), Value: 25, Index: (0, 2), Value: 75])
```

Note that the `Cell` object which we are trying to remove has the value as `99`, since we consider only `index` for object identification, it removes the `Cell` with index `(0, 1)`.